# X-Ray setup with ECS Fargate (.Net Core)

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-ecs, aws-xray

We have deployed our .net core application as docker image on ECS Fargate. So, want to check how we can enable AWS X-Ray tracing for our application. Do we need to setup daemon on cloud as sidecar container?

Or any other work around or quick solution for the same as sidecar container setup will be time taking solution. However, we need to configure X-Ray as we need it to fix production issues.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you are interested in setting up X-Ray for an application running in ECS Fargate.

This documentation will show you how to setup X-Ray in ECS Fargate.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/deploy_servicelens_CloudWatch_agent_deploy_ECS.html

Here is a sample application for setting up X-Ray in ECS Fargate.

https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-xray-fargate

Comment: The first link redirects to the generic CloudWatch documentation.
The second link contains an example for a JS framework rather than .NET